# quick way to remove all applications from stopped glassfish in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'd like a quick script to remove all applications from glassfish 3.1 from Netbeans.

I work on a couple of different applications. Sometimes, I switch back and forth and I'd want to start glassfish without starting all previously deployed applications.

Most of the time, I just remove all "application" and "application-ref" elements from domain.xml.

Can I do the same with a simple trick (ant task or something else)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easiest trick... save a copy of the domain.xml file from a clean install (before you start deploying applications) and then replace the domain.xml with your 'clean copy' as you see fit.

you can also modify the domain a bit (like register resources and the like) and save that domain.xml, if you have a lot of configuration that you needs to happen for your apps.